# Use Umbraco .NET Custom Control

Tags: model-view-controller, razor, umbraco, umbraco6

I want to use Umbraco .NET Custom Control in Macro.
I have gone through following steps:

1) I have created new Macro with name **TestProperty**
[image: Adding Assembly to Macro]

2) Browse and Add Pramater from Assembly
[image: Brose and Save Property in Umbraco]

3) Use Macro in **Template**
[image]

I did not get any problem till last step. But when i am previewing my **Content** then I am getting Page with Error as Below:

[image]

How can I get my Property Value in this case?

Answer (score 0):

TestProperty is an Int. Try

```
new {TestProperty=2}
```

See http://blog.darren-ferguson.com/2014/05/13/typed-access-to-umbraco-marco-parameters-in-partial-views/

Comment: Thanks but its not solving my problem. Still getting same issue